# Does purchased music count against my storage quotas?

Tags: ubuntu-one, quota

For some reason I was under the impression that music purchased from the Ubuntu One store didn't count against my storage quota, but after I purchased a few albums I see that I haves less storage available.

Is purchased music supposed to count against your Ubuntu One cloud storage quota?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, music (purchased from us or otherwise) does count against your storage quota; however, quota is not taken into account when purchasing songs. So you can continue buying songs and they will be delivered to your account and all your machines that are syncing the folder, even though you're over quota.

This is actually a [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhatHappensIfIGoOverMyStorageQuotaByPurchasingMusic):

> ## What happens if I go over my storage quota by purchasing music?
>
> The music store will permit you to buy
>   more music when you are over your
>   storage quota. If you are over your
>   storage quota, you will not be able to
>   add more files to your account from
>   your desktop or from the web until you
>   remove enough files to get under your
>   quota.

Comment: I saw that, but the way I read it didn't answer my question.Does it mean that the music does count against your quota? For example, I have 2gb quota with 1.5 gb of my own stuff and 1 gb of purchased music. Does that mean I can't add any more of my own stuff because I'm over quota?

Comment: I read it over a few more times, so I think the answer is "Yes, it does count against your quota, but they'll still let you download buy music if you are over your quota". If you can say something like that before the FAQ quote, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Chipaca. This is a very clear answer with your update.